# Do I need to cross immigration to collect my baggage at FCO

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, fco

I am travelling from New Delhi, India to Halifax, Canada on a student Visa through Air India (New Delhi-Rome) and Air Canada (Rome-Halifax).

My tickets are on a single booking but have different PNR due to change of airlines. My Air India flight arrives at Terminal 3 and my Air Canada flight also leaves from the same terminal.

I have a 16 hour layover in Rome (FCO) and I plan to stay inside the International Transit Area. However I will need to re check-in my baggage. Do I need to cross immigration to collect my baggage and if yes, will I need a transit visa for it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple PNRs, it's possibly *not* a single booking, but two separate tickets. Better check directly with the airline to see if you can have your baggage checked through or if you absolutely must re-check it yourself.

According to the [Roma Self Connect](http://www.adr.it/web/aeroporti-di-roma-en-/pax-fco-flight-connections) tool on the website of FCO, you'll have to go through immigration, collect and recheck your baggage and then go through Schengen exit again. For that you will likely need an ordinary Schengen visa (unless your nationality makes you eligible for visa-free entry).

Comment: Due to the vagaries of airline reservation systems, you sometimes do have multiple PNRs for a single booking when multiple airlines are involved ([example](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1744768-multiple-pnrs-same-flights-1-booking.html)). It doesn't inherently mean the agent did something bad. I'd check with the airline to see whether or not you do, in fact, have a single booking and whether they'll be able to check your luggage through to Halifax.

Comment: @ZachLipton Fair point, edited.

Comment: Thank you for your response gentlemen. I'm fairly sure that it's a single booking as the e-ticket number is same through all flights.